# Django Prefix the PK ID field of a Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I don't want to use Django's own Primary Key it adds automatically to the model. Is the following possible...

Prefix the PK ID field with `j1_`, followed by a unique ID in base 36. For example, `j1_15bfi0`.

I have read about auto field i.e.

> id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

But this does not seem to have the options to prefix or set how the PK is determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In don't understand what you mean by "Prefix the PK ID field with j1_, followed by a unique ID in base 36"... But anyway: of course you can use whatever field type (including your own custem field type) you want as primary key - you just have to specify it as being the primary key, cf [the fine manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#primary-key).